# How to map the object properties from the list and append it to string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

Definitely there are all import and export functions are there, I reduced code for understanding. I am trying to set values for map function and, once I have
them, I am appending it to URL like from below `contentList` I want to append `login,payment` to URL.

So I have URL `serviceCall?contentList=` and I want to append like `serviceCall?contentList=login,payment`, but it's not happening. Any idea what is implemented wrong while mapping the object?

interface.ts

```
export interface IApiName {
    optionalQueryString?: Map<string, string>;
}
```

main.ts

```
const args = {"contentList":"login,payment","tag":"newFlag"}    
const apiName:IApiName    
apiName.optionalQueryString = this.createMapObject(args);    

if (apiName.optionalQueryString && apiName.optionalQueryString.keys.length > 0) {
    let queryStr: string = "?";

    apiName.optionalQueryString.forEach((value, key) => {
      queryStr += key + "=" + value + "&";
    });

    apiConfig.Url += "/" + queryStr.substr(0, queryStr.length - 1);
}      

private createMapObject (obj) {
    const map = new Map();
    for (const member in obj) {
        console.log('MEMBER', member);
        console.log('OBJECTMEMEBR',  obj[member]);
        map.set(member, obj[member]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
Map.keys();
```

you get an Iterator object that contains the keys, so it does not contains length property.
You want to call

```
apiName.optionalQueryString.size > 0
```

**Map.size** - Returns the number of key/value pairs in the Map object.The good thing is, Map keep the size always updated so you always get the current size of the pairs.